# arcmap mapping information of 2 layers, how to get rid of non-related results

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, buffer, intersection, mapping

I have 2 layers on the map: 1 drain line layer and 1 segment layer. The segment layer is covered by the drain line layer.

Now I want to get the corresponding attribute values on drainline layer which at the same place of the segment.

In order to do that, I do the following things:
(1) create a buffer at the segment layer
(2) create an intersect at the buffer and the drainline layer

After that I can read the mapping information of the darinline and the segment from the intersect. But there are extra feature that not from the segment also be involved in the intersect. The result of the intersect is as follows:

[image]

I don't want the The features within the blue circle because it not relevant to the segment layer.

Is there a way to avoid the useless feature from the drain line layer? Or is there other ways to mapping the data of the 2 layers?

I am using arcmap 10.2.

Answer (score 2):

You can select by location the features in the blue circle, e.g. using the rules "touch the boundary of" your buffer, then select from the selected feature using "within" your buffer.

In your case, you could also select based on the length (they are very small compared with other lines), but the first method is safer.

Once this is done, you can either give a new attribute (so you can use a definition query to hide them but they still exist), or you can simply delete them (in an edit dession).